# Website Redirecting to mysite.azurewebsites.net except while logged in as Admin

Tags: azure, dns, azure-web-app-service

I recently moved my website from hostgator to azure websites but I want to keep the same domain. I've made all the correct DNS changes custom domain configuration in Azure but it redirects to mysite.azurewebsites.net once I click on a link in the site. The strange thing is this doesn't happen when I'm logged in as Admin.

Any ideas? Thanks

Comment: What is the website built on? Wordpress? If yes, did you change the Settings for the site on Wordpress and make sure it has the proper domain?

Comment: Yes it's on Wordpress and yes I've changed the settings in Wordpress to point to the proper domain. As I said it's working only when I'm logged in as Admin but not when I log out.

Comment: @Soulipsyz - Could you update your question to include the steps you used to migrate your WordPress application to Web App?